# Which profit formula should be used for this problem?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

*An item that costs 28 dollars to purchase is sold for 12% profit. About how many items need to be sold to make a $20,000 profit?*

I'm not sure if I should be using an exponential equation or a profit formula to solve this problem. I do know that the answer is 6000 units.

How do I go about setting up this problem?

Comment: Looks like you can simply use a linear equation, does it not?

Comment: How many dollars do you make in profit if you sell one unit?  $10$ units?  $N$ units?  Note:  the answer should be the number of units, not a dollar figure.

Comment: 0.12(28)N = 20000? That would give me N = 1664, which does not match the correct answer.

Comment: Why would you write $12x+28$?  That seems to have no connection to the problem.  Again, suppose you sell one item.  How much profit do you make?

Comment: At N = 1, 0.12(28)(1) = $3.36 of profit.

Comment: Agreed.  So how many do you need to sell to make $\$20,000$?

Comment: Like I mentioned earlier, if 0.12(28)N = 20000, N = 1664. But that doesn't match the correct answer, which is N = 6000.

Comment: Note:  the posted solution from @RossMillikan is correct in saying that it isn't clear what $12\%$ profit means in this context.  I agree with your interpretation, but the other is perfectly sensible.

Comment: Well, let's just see.  You are saying that $\frac {20000}{3.36}=1664$?  That seems obviously wrong.

Comment: You're right. I made a miscalculation. 20000/(0.12*28)=5952. Problem solved. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends a bit on whether the percentage of profit is taken on the cost or on the selling price.

If it is on cost, the profit on each item is $28 \cdot 0.12=3.36$  Then to make $20000$ you need to sell $\frac {20000}{3.36}\approx 5952$ of them.

If the profit is taken on the selling price, you sold for $\frac {28}{1-0.12}\approx 31.82$ and made $3.82$ each.  You then need to sell $\frac {20000}{3.82}\approx 5236$ of them

Comment: It's taken on cost. But your answer is wrong. It's 5952; not 59524. I think you made a mistake with the decimal point placement.

Comment: Yes, I dropped a decimal.  Thanks